# C++ runtime errors in CodeBlocks when printing strings with cout <<

Tags: c++, string, codeblocks, cout

I recently started using CodeBlocks and began encountering odd runtime errors which I have traced back to printing strings using cout <<. For example, even the following..

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    std::string str;
    str = "Hi!";
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

results in an error. It will compile fine (using Borland) but when I run it I get a pop up window saying 'test.exe has stopped working' and in the console I get the message:

```
Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)   execution time : 1.526 s
Press any key to continue.
```

It compiles and runs fine in MS Visual C++ and with G++ in Ubuntu.. any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers,
Weatherwax

Comment: Doesn't Borland have issues with `std::string` (along with every other part of the standard)?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that code. What happens if you try to step through the code, where does it crash?

Comment: What version of Borland? 5.1 and 5.5 have known bugs with this from what I am finding online.

Comment: http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=13737.0;prev_next=prev
This guy had a similar issue and it ended up being a linker issue which he fixed. The fix is the last post in the thread, although reading the whole thread could be useful for you. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks @DeanKnight ! The fix in your link worked for me. I didn't expect that the issue would be as fundamental as that, given that it's hardly a niche feature? Oh well, thanks again.

Comment: @chris is there any compiler in particular that you would recommend, or that is regarded as the 'gold standard'?

Comment: I'm not Chris, but Visual Studios compiler is good. Also GCC/G++ is good. I use VS2010 when at home working on game development stuff and I use GCC and G++ at work. My work relies on GCC and G++ to ship our embedded software, so you can definitely rely on it as a compiler. Also a lot of game development companies use Visual Studio so again, a tried and true compiler.
If you want an IDE Visual Studio is great. Cant beat its debugger. I also started with code::blocks and I remember wasting so much time chasing down dumb issues :)

Comment: Also, I am glad that solution worked for you. I will package it up as an answer for reference by future users.

Comment: @chris Yes, the aging compiler the OP is using does have some issues with standard compliance but that isn't the cause for his program crashing. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My one-off comment ended up helping solve the problem so here it is packaged up as an answer for future users:

> [This](http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=13737.0;prev_next=prev) guy had a similar issue and it ended up being a linker issue which he
>   fixed. The fix is the last post in the thread, although reading the
>   whole thread could be useful for you.

Long Story short: Borland compiler is a bit dated and annoying to use. Ended up being a linker issue within borland. Better off using a different compiler like GCC/G++ or Visual Studio compiler.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is here to elaborate on the root cause of the issue.

The reason for your crashing program is because the wrong runtime library is being linked. Specifically, your example is compiled as a *single threaded* object file(the default) but the linking step is using the *multithreaded* `cw32mt.lib` runtime -- the "mt" suffix at the end means multithreaded.

The solution is to make sure the runtime your program is compiled to use matches with the runtime you're linking against. A few ways to do this.

Important bcc32 compile switches:

```
-tW    Windows GUI program. WinMain() is expected
-tWC   Windows Console program. main() is expected. default.
-tWR   Use dynamically linked runtime. Absence implies static runtime linkage.
-tWM   Use multithreaded runtime. Absence implies single thread.
```

Compiling your example program as single threaded like this works:

> bcc32 -oexample.obj -c example.cpp
>   ilink32 -ap example.obj c0x32, example.exe,, cw32.lib import32.lib,,

or you can compile it as multithreaded like this(note the `-tWM` switch matching up with `cw32mt.lib`):

> bcc32 -tWM -oexample.obj -c example.cpp
>   ilink32 -ap example.obj c0x32, example.exe,, cw32mt.lib import32.lib,,

A third approach that is easier and less error prone is to not call the linker yourself. Instead, let the compiler drive the linker indirectly(similar to gcc):

> bcc32 -tWM -oexample.obj -c example.cpp
>   bcc32 -tWM example.obj -eexample.exe

For your simple example, it can even be shortened to:

> bcc32 -eexample.exe example.cpp

Lastly, you can pass the `-tW` switch multiple times. For example, this command compiles your example as a console program with multithread support and dynamic runtime linkage:

> bcc32 -tWM -tWR -tWC -eexample.exe example.cpp

The produced `example.exe` executable is much smaller and its import table has an entry for `CC3250MT.DLL` confirming that the borland runtime is dynamically linked.

We should not assume that a non-functioning program is caused by nonconformity to the standard or a bug in the tool we're using *without* first investigating user error as a potential cause (even though in this case it's tempting to do so). In the OP's case, the code::block IDE didn't have the right commands setup for the toolchain being used.

Comment: Thanks greatwolf - that's an excellent (and very kind) answer. I have a much better idea what's going on now